# Android Fragment Navigation

Tags: android-fragments

I have a screen with 4 fragments inside it:frag1,frag2,frag3,frag4.In frag1,there is a listview displaying some items.So frag1 is a listfragment. Now on the click of listitem i want to replace frag3 with a new listfragment frag5. Remember frag3 is there in the screen layout file but the new frag5 is not there in the layout.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `frag3` in the layout file. Instead you have to use `FrameLayout` in your layout file which acts as a fragment container and add the fragment to that container dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As already said - do not put fragments in your XML layout files directly. Use empty container (like FrameLayout) and replace its content. My approach is to tag each fragment thats ends in certain container **with the same tag** (so tag is unique per container and since I got one fragment per container, there's no conflict). Then you simply replace fragment with that tag with new one fragment when you need to do that.  And since it's safe to replace tagged fragment even if you in fact got no fragment in container yet, you do not need to bother with checking yourself.